# How to find the position of the primary key which is varchar GUID generated by application row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So my use case is i have to find the location of the primary key column so that i can write query like `select * from my_table where ID <='00000536-37ee-471c-a8e0-3d233b8102f5'`

So my table has a primary key which is varchar type and values of the column is GUID generated by an application.
Here is an example of primary key

```
000000bd-104e-4fd6-a791-c5422f29e1b5
0000016e-7e68-4453-b360-7ffd1627dc22
00000196-2dba-4532-8cba-1e853c466697
0000025a-cfae-41b4-b8e7-ef854d49e54a
00000260-8bdb-4b30-acdb-5a67efd4dbfe
00000366-552d-48a0-b8a1-20190ccd087c
000003f2-d6d8-4a51-96cc-407063bc568b
000003ff-3d16-4e88-9cf3-bcdf01c39a2b
00000487-1e6c-4d6d-a683-6f11d517962c
000004cc-6359-4a9a-aa2a-70a6b73a06b1
00000536-37ee-471c-a8e0-3d233b8102f5
```

Now i need to use this table in aws DMS which accepts only query like select * from table where column =,<=,>=

My use case is to find the exact location of the millions of GUID so that i can divide table into multiple query and select based on GUID .
For example if we have 100th GID is 00000536-37ee-471c-a8e0-3d233b8102f5 then i can write query like `select * from my table where GUID <=100`

The limitation is i can not add any new columns in the existing table because application impact is huge .

How can i do this ?

One Option that i thought but wanted to confirm is below

1. Create a temp table
2. Temp table will have auto generated sequence and ID column
3. Inset into temp table select only GUID from main table with order of GUID .

In this case the value will be stored on order and i an first select GUID based on 100th number and then i can pass that GUID and write my oroginal query

But i am not sure whether this will work on not 
Can some one suggest on this or suggest some other option ?

**So let me explain what i want .**

I want DMS to read may main table in parallel and migrate .
So lets say one DMS task can read nd migrate from 1 to 100,another 100 to 200 another >200 like that .

Currently i can not do because we dont know the position of the primary key and write the query .

Comment: Perhaps the ROWNUM [pseudo column](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Pseudo-column) can help?

Comment: Is the physical order of the rows stored in the table important to you? In Oracle this is arbitrary and has nothing to do with order of insert. If you just need to identify the 100th row returned in your query results then ROWNUM would work, but ROWNUM only applies to the sorted rows in your query results, it has nothing to do with the actual order of rows stored in the table, which can change as rows are inserted, updated, and deleted. If you needed to know which was the 100th row inserted then you would have to track the insert date as a column and sort by that, then filter by ROWNUM=100.

Comment: @pmdba yes physical stored order will work for me..

Comment: Do you know in which table and column the primary key is stored?

Comment: @wolφi yes it is stored in main table...

Comment: OK. Do you want just a sample of 1/100 of the rows or do you want all rows, but split into packs of 100 rows each? Perhaps if you edit your question and explain what you want to do with the rows, people will find an answer that fits your purpose better...

Comment: @wolφi just updated my question ..Please have a look at last part .I want all rows which i will migrate to aws .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide your table into chunks of equal sizes, I would take advantage of the hexadecimal nature of the GUIDs. It will be 256 instead of 100 chunks, but this might be acceptable.

```
CREATE TABLE t (pk VARCHAR2(36) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('000000bd-104e-4fd6-a791-c5422f29e1b5');
```

The easiest option would be

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE pk LIKE '%b5';
```

A bit more advanced:

```
SELECT pk, to_number(substr(pk, -2),'xx') FROM t;
```

If you have millions of rows, this is probably faster:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD (mycol GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_number(substr(pk, -2),'xx')));
CREATE INDEX i ON t(mycol);

SELECT * FROM t WHERE mycol=181;
```

Once your migration is done, you can undo the additional virtual column:

```
DROP INDEX i;
ALTER TABLE t DROP (mycol);
```

Comment: DMS does not have option to write query such as LIKE .Thats the while reason i am asking this question .DMS work only on select * from table where column=''.